# cancel/interupt reqeust AXIOS request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

maybe it's a simple question.

I want to ask how to interrupt axios request in nuxt/vue.

this is my scenarios:

1. I am in page Profile with a HTTP request getProfile and getFullProfile, getProfile request success resolved with but getFullProfile request not yet resolved.
2. Move to product page, the request getFullProfile still waiting response

what i expect

1. I am in page Profile with a HTTP request getProfile and getFullProfile, getProfile request success resolved with but getFullProfile request not yet resolved.
2. Move to product page, the request getFullProfile interupt/cancel

I am using axios as a plugin, this is my config

```
// plugins/axios.js

 app.$axios.setHeader('accept-encoding', null)
    app.$axios.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    app.$axios.setHeader('Authorization', token)
    app.$axios.onError(async error => {
        if (typeof error.response !== "undefined") {
            if (error.response.status === 401) {
                jscookie.set("fallback_url", window.$nuxt.$route.path)
                jscookie.remove('token');
                window.location.href = '/logout'
                return
            }
            return Promise.reject(error);
        } else {
            throw error
        }
    })
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try Axios cancellation? This is the first and likely the only thing you need here.

Comment: aaah i see @EstusFlask i'll check it first